# AVD: getting `[: not found` on `adb shell type [`

Tags: android, shell, adb, android-virtual-device

I'm running android virtual device on 4.0.3 API level 15.

I am trying to execute some commands that rely on `[` or `test`.
However if I do

```
adb shell type [
```

I get

```
[: not found
```

This have worked me previously. Since I've updated my quite old android SDK it does not work any more. I do not understand why was this changed and how to install `[` or the other utils-like binaries.

```
type sh
sh is a tracked alias for /system/bin/sh
ls -l /system/bin/sh
lrwxr-xr-x root     shell             2012-03-27 23:21 sh -> ash
```

I do not know what shell did I use previously on the AVD. On my real device it is `mksh` and it says `[ is a shell builtin`.

Was the shell changed in the AVDs and how could I restore a previous version that has `[`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ADT bundle. The other path is so complex that I suggest you to use the ADT Bundle instead.

```
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
```